In react, formik and yup how to skip validation if dynamic array value if undefined or empty make it optional
This is my aaray : 
translator_services: (4) [empty × 3, {translator_category_description: "sa",translator_category_id: "6672a5a8b07e9bc1b7e36a5c",translator_category_type_id: ['6672a5a8b07e9bc1b7e36a5a']}]

This the error from Yup  :
translator_services: Array(3)<br>
0: {translator_category_id: 'Required', translator_category_description: 'Description is required.'}<br>
1: {translator_category_id: 'Required', translator_category_description: 'Description is required.'}<br>
2: {translator_category_id: 'Required', translator_category_description: 'Description is required.'}<br>

This is validation code :
translator_services: Yup.array().of(
    Yup.object().shape({
      translator_category_id:
        Yup.string().required("Required"),
      translator_category_description:
        Yup.string().nullable().required("Description is required."),
      
      translator_category_type_id: Yup.array().nullable().min(
        1,
        "Select at least one service type"
      ),
    })
  ),


Should only validate if the array value is defined or not empty else skip the validation.
Thanks in advance

What you need to use for this cases is the .when() function.
Here's the docs about it: https://github.com/jquense/yup?tab=readme-ov-file#schemawhenkeys-string--string-builder-object--values-any-schema--schema-schema
So, your code could be something like:
 translator_services: Yup.array().of(
  Yup.object().shape({
    translator_category_id: Yup.string()
     .when('translator_category_type_id', {
       is: (val) => val.length, 
       then: Yup.string().required("Required"), // If translator_category_type_id has values, then translator_category_id is required
        otherwise: Yup.string(),
        }),
        translator_category_description: Yup.string().nullable()
        .when('translator_category_type_id', {
          is: (val) => val.length, 
          then: Yup.string().required("Description is required."),// If translator_category_type_id has values, then translator_category_description is required
          otherwise: Yup.string(),
        }),
        translator_category_type_id: Yup.array().nullable().min(
          1,
          "Select at least one service type"
        ),
      })
    )

Hope it helps!

I made little changes but you code worked... Thank you @laura
